# If Condition Doesnot Work on Foreach Statement PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, echo

so i want to make Dynamic Fontawesome Icons when if statement is match with the condition

```
foreach ($facility as $facility  => $fac) {
     echo  '<div class="col-span-4">';
     echo  '<div class="flex w-full">';
     if ($fac == 'Air Conditioner') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-fan"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Cable Tv') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-tv"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Dining Area') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Electricity') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-plug"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Garage') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Gazebo') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Internet') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Kitchen') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="far fa-hat-chef"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Level') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Pool') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-swimmer"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Security') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fad fa-shield"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Storage') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-box"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Washer or Laundry') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-washer"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Water Resource') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-water"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Wi-Fi') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-wifi"></i></div>';
     }
     echo  '<p>' . $fac . '</p>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '</div>';
}
```

Echo at the bottom to showing the variable value are correctly showing the available array item of the $facility, but the condition doesnot work, it only work once which is the Air Conditioner only. Some body know where i goes wrong here?

Comment: `$facility as $facility` Use different naming here, f.e. `$facilities as $facility`. And have you made sure that `$fac` doesn't contain any whitespace?

Comment: I already try to using different naming, but result are same, if there is whitespace, how can i get rid of it in my case, this is the quick result for that code [link](https://ibb.co/wBbxjvL)

Comment: @GusdeWidnyana Please show code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of code repeated unnecessarily. Let PHP do the work for you. Consider, if every line is the same except one tiny section, you only need to repeat that tiny section.

```
<?php
//create a key-value pair so you don't have to have an IF statement for each condition
$facility_map = [
    'air_conditioner' => 'fan',
    'cable_tv' => 'tv',
    'dining_area' => 'utensils',
    'electricity' => 'plug',
    'garage' => 'warehouse',
    'gazebo' => 'home',
    'internet' => 'globe',
    'kitchen' => 'chef',
    'level' => 'level-up-alt',
    'pool' => 'swimmer',
    'security' => 'shield',
    'storage' => 'box',
    'washer_or_laundry' => 'washer',
    'water_resource' => 'water',
    'wi-fi' => 'wifi'
];

foreach($facility as $fac) {

    //trim whitespae at the beginning and end, lowercase everything, change spaced to underscores. Easier to look up in array
    $fac_cleaned = str_replace(' ', '_', trim(strtolower($fac)));

    //check if key in map exists? If not, print and move to next key
    if(!array_key_exists($fac_cleaned, $facility_map)) {
        echo "Unhandled Key ({$fac_cleaned})<br>";
        continue;
    }

    //grab the value from the $facility_map array
    $icon = $facility_map[$fac_cleaned];

    ?>
        <div class="col-span-4">
            <div class="flex w-full">
                <div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="far fa-<?= $icon ?>"></i></div>
                <p><?= $fac ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

This method has a pretty big advantage in that it is very easily expanded. You can just add more values to the `$facility_map` array, or you could even generate that array from a database.

Comment: This is good, but the result are same, only air conditioner get the Fontawesome emoticon

Comment: @DanielW. Chill out Dude, Here is $facility Array Data ```Array ( [0] => Air Conditioner [1] => Cable Tv [2] => Dining Area [3] => Electricity [4] => Gazebo [5] => Kitchen [6] => Pool [7] => Storage [8] => Water Resource )```

Comment: @GusdeWidnyana If you run this code, you'll see it will print something like "Unhandled Key", and tell you which ones don't match up. Then you just have to modify your `$facility_map` to match. If you aren't getting that message, then maybe the icon doesn't exist by the name in `$facility_map`

Answer (score -1):

You can use foreach like that

```
foreach (iterable_expression as $value){
//commands
}
```

or

```
foreach (iterable_expression as $key => $value){
    //commandes
}
```

Try this :

```
foreach ($facilityList as $facility  => $fac) {
     echo  '<div class="col-span-4">';
     echo  '<div class="flex w-full">';
     if ($fac == 'Air Conditioner') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-fan"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Cable Tv') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-tv"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Dining Area') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Electricity') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-plug"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Garage') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Gazebo') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Internet') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Kitchen') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="far fa-hat-chef"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Level') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Pool') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-swimmer"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Security') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fad fa-shield"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Storage') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-box"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Washer or Laundry') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-washer"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Water Resource') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-water"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Wi-Fi') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-wifi"></i></div>';
     }
     echo  '<p>' . $fac . '</p>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Apparently Result are same , look at this pictures [Images](https://ibb.co/wBbxjvL)

Comment: foreach ($facility as $fac ){ ... } try this

Comment: Same Result, Nothing Change

Comment: can I see your controller please ?

Comment: Here is The $facility Array Value ```Array ( [0] => Air Conditioner [1] => Cable Tv [2] => Dining Area [3] => Electricity [4] => Gazebo [5] => Kitchen [6] => Pool [7] => Storage [8] => Water Resource )```

Answer (score -1):

This work for me....

```
<?php
$facilityList = [
    'air_conditioner' => 'fan',
    'cable_tv' => 'tv',
    'dining_area' => 'utensils',
    'electricity' => 'plug',
    'garage' => 'warehouse',
    'gazebo' => 'home',
    'internet' => 'globe',
    'kitchen' => 'chef',
    'level' => 'level-up-alt',
    'pool' => 'swimmer',
    'security' => 'shield',
    'storage' => 'box',
    'washer_or_laundry' => 'washer',
    'water_resource' => 'water',
    'wi-fi' => 'wifi'
];


foreach ($facilityList as $facility  => $fac) {
     echo  '<div class="col-span-4">';
     echo  '<div class="flex w-full">';
     if ($fac == 'Air Conditioner') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-fan"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Cable Tv') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-tv"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Dining Area') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Electricity') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-plug"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Garage') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Gazebo') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Internet') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Kitchen') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="far fa-hat-chef"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Level') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Pool') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-swimmer"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Security') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fad fa-shield"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Storage') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-box"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Washer or Laundry') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-washer"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Water Resource') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-water"></i></div>';
     } else if ($fac == 'Wi-Fi') {
        echo '<div class="w-8 text-bvr20"><i class="fas fa-wifi"></i></div>';
     }
     echo  '<p>' . $fac . '</p>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense... You copied the map from my answer, and applied it incorrectly to the original foreach loop from the question. This code won't work, because none of the if statements will be true, as `$fac` will never be equal to any of those values. Also, this assumes OP wants to loop over the array map, instead of the values they were looping over originally.